# Получить значение из ячейки DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

Есть dataGrid. При щелчке по строке этого грида в метод передается значение ячейки этой строки. 
Xaml грида :

```
      <DataGrid x:Name="DGInvestment" ItemsSource="{Binding InvestCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">

            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectDetails}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>

                <DataGrid.Columns>
                  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column1" MinWidth="200" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Type}"/>
                  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column2" MinWidth="200" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Date}"/>
               </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Коллекция из вьюмодели :

```
    public ObservableCollection<Invest> InvestCollection { get; set; }
    public class Invest
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
    }
```

Заполняется в конструкторе :

```
        InvestCollection = new ObservableCollection<Invest>();
        InvestCollection.Add(new Invest() { Type = " type" });
        InvestCollection.Add(new Invest() { Date= " date" });
```

И метод в самой вьюшке который должен принимать значение из ячейки грида :

```
    public ICommand SelectDetails
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(delegate() 
            {
            //..........
            });
        }
    }
```

Собственно вопрос - как в `SelectDetails` получить значение определенного столбца той строки, на которую нажал пользователь ? Использую Mvvm Light

Comment: у DataGrid есть свойство selectedItem, попробуйте использовать его

Comment: А правда, почему не SelectedItem? Вам не нужно вовсе привязывать команду к клику.

Answer (score 2):

1. В ViewModel определяем:

   ```
   private Invest selectedInvest = new Invest();

   public Invest SelectedInvest
   {

   get{

       return selectedInvest;
   }   
   set{

      if (selectedInvest == value) return;

      selectedInvest = value;

      RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedInvest");
      // сюда можно добавить что должно выполняться когда выбранный элемент 
     // изменится
     }
   }
   ```

   `
2. Как уже советовал user2455111
   используйте SelectedItem:

   ```
    <DataGrid x:Name="DGInvestment" ItemsSource="{Binding InvestCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedInvest, Mode=TwoWay}"
   ```

P.S: ICommand SelectDetails должна быть определена в ViewModel, а не в View.
Иначе не выйдет присоединить команду к View. Вы используете Binding. Binding ищет указанную команду в DataContext, а это ViewModel.

Comment: зачем мне RaisePropertyChanged для Entity если работаю с ADO ?

Comment: Это не для Entity. GalaSoft.MvvmLight.ObservableObject.RaisePropertyChanged

Comment: для нестатического свойства требуется ссылка на обьект

Comment: Это Вы сейчас к чему?
Если Вы имеете в виду GalaSoft.MvvmLight.ObservableObject.RaisePropertyChanged - это я просто указал namespace.